# WPF DataGrid / LINQ Query (DataGrid new row not visible)

Tags: wpf, vb.net, linq

I'm relatively new to WPF/LINQ2Entities.  I've managed to make progress but I am stuck on one issue that I've been researching:

1) I have a WPF DataGrid that is populated based on this CollectionViewSource.  The CollectionViewSource's source is a LINQ query.

```
    Private context As New QADBEntities        
    Dim QADBEntitiesViewSource As CollectionViewSource

    Dim SalesOrderSerialNumber_Query = From salesOrders In context.tblSalesOrders
                           Join serialNumbers In context.tblSerialNumbers
                           On salesOrders.Sales_Order_ID Equals serialNumbers.Sales_Order_ID
                           Where salesOrders.Sales_Order_ID = 5
                           Select New With {salesOrders, serialNumbers}


    QADBEntitiesViewSource = CType(Me.FindResource("QADBEntitiesViewSource"), CollectionViewSource)
    QADBEntitiesViewSource.Source = SalesOrderSerialNumber_Query.ToList()
```

Here is an excerpt from the XAML for the DataGrid:

```
            <DataGrid x:Name="TblSerialNumbersDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" CanUserAddRows="True"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource QADBEntitiesViewSource}}" Margin="293,44,10,16" 
              RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
              <DataGrid.Columns>
                  <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Kit_Group_IDColumn" Binding="{Binding serialNumbers.Kit_Group_ID}" Header="Kit Group ID" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
                  <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="NotesColumn" Binding="{Binding serialNumbers.Notes}" Header="Notes" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
                  <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Product_IDColumn" Binding="{Binding serialNumbers.Product_ID}" Header="Product ID" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
                  <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Production_Lead_IDColumn" Binding="{Binding serialNumbers.Production_Lead_ID}" Header="Production Lead ID" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
                  <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="QA_Personnel_IDColumn" Binding="{Binding serialNumbers.QA_Personnel_ID}" Header="QA Personnel ID" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
                  <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Sales_Order_IDColumn" Binding="{Binding serialNumbers.Sales_Order_ID}" Header="Sales Order ID" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
                ....etc
              </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

2) The problem: Populating the DataGrid and making changes to the data *works just fine*.  However, **the DataGrid is not showing the new row at the bottom of the grid to add additional records**.

I believe it has something to do with the LINQ query, because when I populate a DataGrid in this way:

```
            QADBEntitiesViewSource = CType(Me.FindResource("QADBEntitiesViewSource"), CollectionViewSource)
            QADBEntitiesViewSource.Source = context.SalesOrderListSQ.ToList()
```

....everything, including the new row, is functional.  Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciate.  Again I'm pretty new to this and I realize it could be a problem with my design as a whole.  Thanks.

Comment: Just a guess: maybe the problem is that `CollectionViewSource` is read-only.  As a quick test I'd try using an `ObservableCollection` or similar as the source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the problem here is not with LINQtoEntities and not with the Grid, but with EF. EF supports changes to the objects in a collection, and even change notification if you add rows to a table (i.e. items to an ObjectSet), but not automatic adding of rows through a CollectionViewSource. If you want that, you can go back to a DataSet, or just create an "Add New" command which adds a new item to the ObjectSet and makes it the current item of the CollectionViewSource.

You can refresh the CollectionViewSource by calling CollectionViewSource.View.Refresh, and you can make a certain item the current item by calling CollectionViewSource.View.MoveCurrentTo(newItem). However, in case of your object query, you might have to run the query again, i.e. repeat the line CollectionViewSource.Source = ...

I found EF's support for collection view sources erratic; it depends very much on how exactly you get your entity list what is supported and what not. Your first code returns an ObjectQuery, which must be executed again in order to recognise changes to the underlying list, while the second example returns an ObjectSet, which supports adding and removing items and also collection change notification, as far as I know. So, in fact I shoul dsay in the first paragraph that EF supports adding rows through a CollectionViewSource only in some cases...

Comment: I found out what you meant by an add new command, which worked fine.  Now I just need to find out how to refresh the table or "make it the current item of the CollectionViewSource" as you said.  I don't really want to go to dataset because I think LINQtoEntities is the way to go.  Thanks for the help.  But I'm still not sure I understand why on another DataGrid (see last code snippet) I am able to add new records via the new row using EF and databinding.  Am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: hbarck -- That answered most of my questions.  Greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: And also, this is just a peripheral question to answer, if you have time:  Do you have any suggestions on the best/efficient route to work with DataGrids and LINQtoEntities queries for data manipulation?  I'm realizing that there is more than one way to accomplish this, but is there a standard practice that most people seem to find effective?  I'm finding that using CollectionViewSource *works*, but I don't know if it will be best in the long run working with multiple tables/joined queries.

Comment: Sorry, don't know anything about the best way... so far (.net 4.0), I liked neither EF nor DataGrid...

Answer (score 0):

Linq query results are read-only, if you want to be able to add items to your data source you may need to supply your own class as `Source` which enumerates your results (`IEnumerable`) and also supplies methods to manipulate the data source (`IList`).

Comment: H.B. -- much appreciated. I didn't know that about Linq query results.  So it's possible to save changes to the data (which I'm able to do) even if the linq query results are read-only?

Comment: @K.Akins: The collection itself is distinct from its items, any object that is mutable will still be mutable even when it is part of an immutable collection (like the `IEnumerables` that are returned by Linq queries).